# JavaScript :: element.showAlert() not working

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to make a function where I can just put `showAlert()` after an element name and it will show an alert when clicked. I have defined my showAlert function in my JavaScript, but I always get an error.
**I've tried:**

```
        function showAlert() {
             return onclick = "alert('Hello World')"
        }

            document.getElementById('test').showAlert();
```

The code above should return: "`document.getElementById('test').onclick = "alert('Hello World')`",
However, I get an error saying: `document.getElementById(...).showAlert is not a function`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you expect `showAlert()` to be? Also, show the code for the element for `id="test"`

Comment: @Rojo — The function they defined on the previous three lines

Comment: You can use it like: `function showAlert() { alert('Hello World") }` and `<div onclick="showAlert()"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showAlert() {
          alert('Hello World')
        }
        
 document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', showAlert)
```

```html
<div id='test' >x</div>
```

Comment: I know that this is a way to do it but I want it to be a function that can just be placed after any element name, like: document.getElementById('test').showAlert() instead of adding the onclick event to the element.

Comment: snippet updated